# Force recache JSON files in webpack's require

Tags: javascript, json, caching, webpack, loader

I'm using [redux-pagan](https://github.com/alexkuz/redux-pagan) plugin for localization. All locales are stored in JSON files and load on demand by this function (from redux-pagan docs), which uses promise-loader.

```
function getLangData(locale) {
  // here we use promise-loader to load lang data by demand
  return require('promise?global,[name].i18n!json!./i18n/' + locale + '.i18n.json');
}
```

At some point my locale files may be updated or changed so I want to trigger force-recache to clients browsers reload files.
I was thinking about using that old ?v=2 trick but it didn't work. Also I've tried [hash] which didn't help too.

That webpack's require syntax is total mess!
How to trigger force recache of JSON files?

Comment: What's your `output.chunkFilename`?

Comment: Did you have a `[name].i18n.js` in `dist` directory?

Comment: Wow! seems to be chunkFilename is exactly what I needed! It was chunkFilename: '[name].chunk.js', but I changed to '[name].chunk.js?v=[hash]' so it adds hash, exactly as I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: Move it to answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure your `output.chunkFilename`. Use the `[hash]` in the name.